# How to limit gearman job server memory allocate?

Tags: gearman

how to limit gearman job server memory allocate? it seems that gearman job server will not limit its own memory usage. Is there any way to limit the gearman job server not bigger than 1G?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, the gearman server does not currently have an option to limit its memory usage.

However, here are two workarounds:

1. Run gearmand inside a virtual machine like [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).
2. If you are running Linux, try using the `ulimit` command to limit memory usage.

```
$ ulimit -Sv 1000000
$ gearmand [the rest of your command line parameters]

where:
-S Specifies the soft limit for the given resource
-v Specifies virtual memory allocation, in kbytes
```

Comment: use ulimit to limit memory usage may influence other application inside the virtual machine. perhaps docker is a better solution. but I still hope there is  any way to limit the gearman server's own memory.

Comment: Create a separate user account just for running gearman, and ulimit should only affect processes running under that account.